# Jackson: in case of multiple serializers which one is used?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to serialize POJOs. I wrote a custom serializer for string values, and it works fine.

However I am not sure what happens, when two serializers are registered for the same type. In my tests the last one added was used, but I am not sure whether it works that way all the time or not.

**So my question is:** if I add multiple serializers for the same type, which one will be used?

---

Code snippet:

```
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(new CustomSerializer1());
module.addSerializer(new CustomSerializer2());
```

...

```
class CustomSerializer1 extends NonTypedScalarSerializerBase<String>
class CustomSerializer2 extends NonTypedScalarSerializerBase<String>
```

Comment: Another question would be why you would use multiple serializer for the same type. Should never be the case. But for investigating and curiousity it's a good question.

Comment: There could be many reasons @Nico. E.g. one for serialising to (private) app logs, and one for serialising to a public API.

Comment: Understandable but for those instances a JsonView could be utilised in order to create to distinct json representations of the same object by using the selected JsonView for serialisation., if I'm not completely mistaken now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ideal world, something like this would be clearly specified in the Javadoc of `SimpleModule`, but it unfortunately doesn't seem to be the case here.

The next-best approach is to look at the source, which reveals that [`SimpleModule`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleModule.java) uses the class [`SimpleSerializers`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.15/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.java) to keep track of its configured serializers.

Diving into that reveals the [`_addSerializer`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.15/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.java) method:

```
protected void _addSerializer(Class<?> cls, JsonSerializer<?> ser)
{
    ClassKey key = new ClassKey(cls);
    // Interface or class type?
    if (cls.isInterface()) {
        if (_interfaceMappings == null) {
            _interfaceMappings = new HashMap<ClassKey,JsonSerializer<?>>();
        }
        _interfaceMappings.put(key, ser);
    } else { // nope, class:
        if (_classMappings == null) {
            _classMappings = new HashMap<ClassKey,JsonSerializer<?>>();
        }
        _classMappings.put(key, ser);
        if (cls == Enum.class) {
            _hasEnumSerializer = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Conclusion is the same as the one you've already reached: The last added serializer is used, due to them being stored in a `Map` with their input type as keys. Strictly speaking, there are no guarantees that this will not change in the future though, as it is all internal implementation.

Comment: Links are broken. New URL: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.15/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.java#L227